# How to reload a page in Opera without cache?

Tags: opera, browser-cache

I'm trying to get Opera 11.61 to reload a page without using cache whatsoever. So far I've tried shift-clicking on the reload button, Ctrl-R, Shift-R, F5. None of these work. The only way I've found to do a reload without cache is to open Opera Dragonfly (Opera's developer tools), open the Network tab, and select "Disable all caching" under Network options. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Upgrade to Opera 11.62 which was released a day ago. From the [changelog](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/1162/):

```
Support Ctrl+F5 and Shift+F5 for unconditional reload of web page (bypass cache)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Opera

Use one of the following:

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click the Reload button
on the navigation toolbar.

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and click the Reload button
on the navigation toolbar.

## Internet Explorer

Use one of the following:

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click the "Refresh" button on the toolbar.

## Google Chrome

**On Windows**, use one of the following:

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click the Reload button
on the navigation toolbar.

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and click the Reload button
on the navigation toolbar.

**On Mac OS X:**

Hold both the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> keys
and press the <kbd>R</kbd> key.

**On Linux:**

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

## Firefox and other related browsers

These instructions work for Firefox, SeaMonkey, and other related browsers.

**On Windows and Linux**, use one of the following:

Hold both the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> keys
and then press <kbd>R</kbd>.

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and click the Reload button
on the navigation toolbar.

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

**On Mac OS X**, use one of the following:

Hold both the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> keys
and then press <kbd>R</kbd>.

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and click the Reload button
on the navigation toolbar.

## Safari

For version 4 and newer:

Hold down the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key and click the Reload toolbar button.

For version 3 and older:

Hold down the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key and press <kbd>R</kbd>. 
This kind of "regular" reload will usually bypass the cache.

Note  that  Apple  claims  that  clicking  the  "Reload"  toolbar  button  has  the  same  effect  as  <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but this is not true; frequently the button will not bypass the cache.

## Konqueror

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or click the "Reload" button on the toolbar.

---

[Bypassing cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)

Comment: That's quite thorough. I'd suggest moving opera to the top due to the fact that the question asks how to do it in Opera only.

Comment: In macOS opera it's now option-command-R

Answer (score 0):

How to Force Refresh a Single Page

Before you go straight to clearing your entire browser cache, one trick you can try is something called a “force refresh”. Normally, when you refresh a page, your browser still serves up the cached version of the page, rather than downloading all of the assets again. But you can actually bypass the cache and force a complete refresh by using some simple hotkeys:

***Windows and Linux browsers: CTRL + F5***

Apple Safari: SHIFT + Reload toolbar button
Chrome and Firefox for Mac: CMD + SHIFT + R

Again, this method only bypasses the cache for the specific page that you’re on. It leaves the rest of your browser cache untouched. Therefore, this option is great if you’re experiencing issues with just a single page. But if you want to completely reset your experience (say, across an entire site), you’re better off just clearing your entire browser cache.

[Windows and Linux browsers: CTRL + F5](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/how-to-clear-browser-cache/)

Comment: Ctrl-R reloads the page, too.